# Python post username and password

Tags: python, bash

I wish to access information from this website using Python. But I cannot figure out how to post my log in information using urllib2

https://www.linksyssmartwifi.com/

Can anyone explain why it isn't working?

*Edit - This question has been listed as too broad. I will be more specific.*

When I try to use the following code, I can't seem to 'post' the user name and password to the webpage.

```
import urllib2
auth_handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
auth_handler.add_password(realm=' ??? ',
                      uri=' ??? ',
                      user='USERNAME',
                      passwd='PASSWORD')
opener = urllib2.build_opener(auth_handler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
urllib2.urlopen('EXAMPLELINK')
```

I am assuming this is because there is no string in the url containing the data and/or there is no api on this page that allows for posts. I don't understand WHY it is not working, I don't actually have any error code. If I print the content I've received after urlopen I get the html code of a page, but without having it logged in.

But my understanding here may be incorrect.

I actually would like to find out information about how many people are logged in to my home network, using a remote connection. I'm assuming this is the only way. I would like to automate some stuff based on who is logged into my local network, the information is available on this page after I log in.

I would preferably like to use Python or Bash scripting to do this.

Comment: can you show us your code and the error you get?

Comment: I would also suggest investigating the Python [requests](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests) library, which is much easier to work with than `urllib2`.

Answer (score 1):

This site does not use basic http authentication so the HTTPBasicAuthHandler you made will not even be called. The site just posts the username and password using SSLv3. I checked it out with [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/).

Also, you may need to create an ssl handler. I had problems with urllib with https and had to use the handler below.

```
import urllib2, ssl
sslv3_handler = urllib2.HTTPSHandler(context=ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv3))
opener = urllib2.build_opener(sslv3_handler)
```